# Validar que no se repita el ID

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de validar que no se ingresen dos estudiantes con el mismo Id al sistema.

```js
function validarCodigoEstudiante(cod){

   var x;
   var codEst = 0;

   if(typeof estudiantes != "undefined" && estudiantes != null && estudiantes.length != null && estudiantes.length > 0){

       for(x in estudiantes){
           
           codEst = estudiantes[x]['codigo'];    

           if(cod == codEst){
               
               alert("No pueden haber dos estudiantes con el mismo codigo!");

               return false;

       }else if(cod != codEst){
         
           return true;
       }
   }
       }else{  

            return true;      
   }
}
```

El problema que no logro resolver es que siempre valida para la posicion 0 del array, por lo que si ingreso dos estudiantes con id = 1; la validacion funciona, pero si ingreso dos estudiantes con id = 2; los agrega porque el encargado de comparar siempre tiene el mismo valor, que es 1.

No he podido resolver hasta el momento, agradezco vuestra ayuda.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas retornando true dentro del bucle `for`.  Necesitas eliminar el `else` dentro del `for` asi:

```
function validarCodigoEstudiante(cod){

   var x;
   var codEst = 0;

   if(typeof estudiantes != "undefined" && estudiantes != null && estudiantes.length != null && estudiantes.length > 0){

       for(x in estudiantes){

           codEst = estudiantes[x]['codigo'];    

           if(cod == codEst){

               alert("No pueden haber dos estudiantes con el mismo codigo!");

               return false;

           }
       }
       return true;      
   } else {
     return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para este problema usaría `some()` itera y retorna `true` o `false`:

```js
const estudiantes = [{"codigo":1},{"codigo":2},{"codigo":3}];

function validarCodigoEstudiante(cod){

    return estudiantes.some(e=>e.codigo === cod);  
 }

 console.log(validarCodigoEstudiante(1));
 console.log(validarCodigoEstudiante(4));
```

Nos dice si ya existe algún elemento con ese código.